# Get an img to display below/behind a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu button. The main blue outline is meant to sit above the image but right now the blue border is behind the image.

**Can you help me figure out what I need to do to get the image behind the blue border?**

I cut the blue border into 2 sections, the top & the bottom. The bottom is a tall image, so that the border can grow/be large for tall images.

This is how the buttom is meant to look:

[image: http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/7940/capturetxr.png]

This is how it currently looks:

[image: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/3051/capture2lf.png]

My Code:

```
<div class="buttonTop">
    <div class="buttonBottom">
        <img class="buttomImg" src="images/ButtonImages/sweets2.jpg" width="150px" height="105px" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>

.buttonTop { 
    background: url(../images/dinnersButton.png) 0 top no-repeat; 
    padding-top: 73px; 
    display: block; 
    width: 153px; 
    height: 113px;
    margin: 0px auto; 
}

.buttonBottom { 
    background: url(../images/buttonBottomLite.png) 0 bottom no-repeat; 
    padding: 0px 2px 5px 2px; 
    display: block; 
    height: 109px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.buttomImg {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I added a jsFiddle to my answer in case you're curious about how it could have been done using your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="round_border">
<img src="" alt="" />
</div>

--- CSS
.round_border {
padding: 5px;
border: 5px solid blue;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

That should work in most modern browsers.

Comment: "Modern Browsers" defined:  IE 8 and below excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The methodology is flawed.  You cannot put something *inside* a `div` while at the same time expect it to appear behind that `div`.  Your `div` has a background image and anything you put inside it will cover the background, period.

You need to re-think the whole thing... each of the three items in their own `div` all within another `div` used as a container.  Then you can put the image `div` behind (under) the border `div`.

EDIT:

The following jsFiddle shows how to put three `div`'s in a container, while having the second two cover the first.  The two `div`'s are transparent to simulate your transparent border PNG which also allows you to see the `div` behind.  The red `div` behind is supposed to represent your photo and it's set to `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/a9cX8/